# Interpreting Mathematica output or producing cleaner output

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, pure-function, inverse

Could someone please explain what the following would look like in standard math notation (or explain to me what this means):

```
InverseFunction[(
   z Log[1 - #1] + (1 - 2 z) Log[#1] + (-1 + z) Log[z - #1 + z #1])/(
   z (-1 + 2 z)) &][-(t/2) + (
  z Log[1 - a0] + Log[a0] - 2 z Log[a0] - Log[z - a0 + z a0] + 
   z Log[z - a0 + z a0])/(z (-1 + 2 z))]
```

I'm new to Mathematica so the use of the pure functions is a little confusing, especially since it's been combined with the inverse.

Also is there a way to get Mathematica to print this without using pure functions?

Comment: "Also is there a way to get Mathematica to print this without using pure functions?" - not really. To interpret something like `InverseFunction[Tan[#] &][x]`, it just says it is the inverse function of `Tan[]` applied to its argument `x`; that is, `ArcTan[]`. Since most functions do not admit an easy representation for the inverse, we sometimes cannot avoid `InverseFunction[]`.

Comment: @J.M. that;s a valid answer from my point of view :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to write it is to let
$$f(x) = \frac{z \log (1-x)+(1-2 z) \log (x)+(z-1) \log
   (x z-x+z)}{z (2 z-1)}$$
and write
$f^{(-1)}\left(\frac{z \log (1-{a_0})-2 z \log
   ({a_0})+z \log ({a_0}
   z-{a_0}+z)-\log ({a_0}
   z-{a_0}+z)+\log ({a_0})}{z (2
   z-1)}-\frac{t}{2}\right)$
for `InverseFunction[..][..]`.
So in regular mathematical notation, the expression is done in two pieces (or sometimes more).  In *Mathematica*, one needs a single expression (to compute with).  I doubt there's a simpler way than `InverseFunction[..][..]`.

Comment: I doubt there's a simpler way to answer. +1